# Overriding font-family via userContent.css doesn't work

Tags: firefox, userchrome.css

I'm trying to override `font-family` via `userContent.css` in all web pages. My ultimate goal is to only target Persian/Arabic text in the css but that's a separate issue.

I started with a simple global rule below but Firefox does not pick it up:

```css
* { 
    font-family: "Vazirmatn" !important; 
}
```

I noticed the changes are picked in firefox's chrome, for instance the text in the Inspector but not in actual websites. I added below to target content of websites but it wasn't effective:

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix('http://'), url-prefix('https://') {
    * { 
        font-family: "Vazirmatn" !important; 
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Some sanity checks:

- `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` is set to True
- the same CSS works if I use the Stylish extension but I prefer to use the native userContent.css if possible
- "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above" is set to True in settings
- I'm on Firefox 106.0.2